# Sorting a date row in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, date

How do you sort by earliest date?

I tried `.sort` and I get

```
<td><%= effort.week_commencing.sort %></td>
// => undefined method `sort' for Mon, 12 Sep 2011:Date
```

The values are not in an array they are listed in a table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `sort` method only on array's.
I don't think `effort.week_commencing` is returning an array in your case.

check what are you getting in effort.week_commencing.

Comment: you can sort the dates only if you are getting an array of dates.

Comment: ok you are getting a singe date that's why its throwing the error.

Comment: If you are are performing it in a loop you can collect all the dates in an array variable and apply sort to it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3655/discussion-between-mahesh-and-ahmet)